# How to Identify form designer file from running mode in C# windows application ?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to find the form designer file from running mode in C# windows application ? eg :In VB 6 we could apply ctrl and break to get into form from running mode.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please refrain your question as it is unclear to distinguish your problem and your desired outcome/result.

Second of all, I do not think there is a way to do this in C# windows application, which one did you mean, Windows Forms or WPF?

Third, I do not know if this will solve your problem but there is a very interesting article I found regarding designing windows application at run time and contained a useful way to obtain this functionality, 
Please take a look at:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823293/Windows-Form-Design-at-Run-Time

Comment: It is Windows Forms.I am working in a  project with more than fifty forms. I need to do a change in 2-3 windows forms.I can navigate to the screens easily on Run mode . It is difficult to open each and every form designer to find out exact form.cs file.Checking an option to find out the respective form.cs file from the run mode.Say eg: when i click on button, if i can jump into respective form.cs file, it will be helpful.

Comment: There is no easy way to achieve this, unless you will use breakpoints on key locations in your code. the other, more difficult way, is to raise events on click that will lead you to the desired form respectively.